# Writting equations in Blogspot

Tags: blogger

I have created a blog in blogspot. What I need to do is to write equation in the blog so adding [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) would be great to add in the blogspot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog on Blogger too, and have made several math-themed posts. However, I haven't tried adding Mathjax to it. That might be a bit too much hassle for the number of equations you want to add to it. How many equations are you planning to post? Will it be for one post only, or several posts?

Up to now, I have just been using an online tool for creating the equations in TeX, converting the TeX to graphics, and then uploading the graphics to the blog. So far, it has worked out pretty good.

Comment: I have many tex file and many completed file which is latex form. So It will be good if the blogger will run these Latex equations.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by latex equations? Latex derives its equations from tex. Latex is a styles framework over the tex equations. I do not think that you need latex for equations. [I have no problems with equations in blogger](http://valjok.blogspot.com/2013/07/characteristic-polynomial-3.html). I use the same tex style as I do in math.stackexchange.

Yet, my template's `<head>` starts with

```
<script src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'>    
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        HTML: [&quot;input/TeX&quot;,&quot;output/HTML-CSS&quot;],
        TeX: { extensions: [&quot;AMSmath.js&quot;,&quot;AMSsymbols.js&quot;], 
               equationNumbers: { autoNumber: &quot;AMS&quot; } },
        extensions: [&quot;tex2jax.js&quot;],
        jax: [&quot;input/TeX&quot;,&quot;output/HTML-CSS&quot;],
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ [&#39;$&#39;,&#39;$&#39;], [&quot;\\(&quot;,&quot;\\)&quot;] ],
                   displayMath: [ [&#39;$$&#39;,&#39;$$&#39;], [&quot;\\[&quot;,&quot;\\]&quot;] ],
                   processEscapes: true },
        &quot;HTML-CSS&quot;: { availableFonts: [&quot;TeX&quot;],
                      linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
    });
</script>
```

It is better [here](http://irrep.blogspot.com/2011/07/mathjax-in-blogger-ii.html)

```
<script src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'>    
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        HTML: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
        TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"], 
               equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } },
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
                   displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
                   processEscapes: true },
        "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"],
                      linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
    });
</script>
```

TeX.SE proposes the same, [Design → Edit HTML → Edit Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13868/29774).